# If statement with textbox color as a condition

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

This is for Access 2007 using VB on a form. I'm trying to run some code when all 3 text boxes are green and if they aren't green a message box will appear asking to correct errors before exporting. Is there a better way to to evaluate 3 conditions? And to read the color value should I use Me.Text1.Value = vbgreen?

I appreciate your help

```
 If Me.Text1 = "vbgreen" And Me.Text3 = "vbgreen" and Me.Text5 = "vbgreen" Then
    Call RunExpZip
    Else
    msg = MsgBox("Please correct errors before exporting", vbCritical)
    End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the text in the textboxes is actually the word "vbgreen" then you need to check the `BackColor` property of the textboxes. (Or `ForeColor` if it is the text-colour, rather than the background.)

This value won't evaluate to `vbGreen` (65280) though; standard green will have the value 5026082:

```
If Me.Text1.BackColor = 5026082 Then
    'etc.
```

Presumably, though, the colour is set using Conditional Formatting. In which case it would be better (in my opinion) to check the conditions (that would make them green) rather than checking the colour itself. (A tiny change to the colour would mean the if-condition(s) will not be met.)

Comment: It is possible to convert `RGB(0,255,0)` or `vbGreen` to 5026082 for comparison but I haven't pursued this in connection with this question.

Comment: The following code worked for me, I appreciate the help and suggestions!                                                               If Me.Text1.BackColor = vbGreen And Me.Text3.BackColor = vbGreen And Me.Text5.BackColor = vbGreen Then
    Call RunExpZip
    Else
    msg = MsgBox("Please correct errors before exporting", vbCritical)
    End If